# Trying to create a sub, but get macro error in VBA

Tags: excel, vba

I am trying to write a sub in VBA that looks like the following,

```
 Public Sub Value(X As Double)

 Code in here...

 End Sub
```

However, whenever I try to run this, it doesn't recognize the Sub I just wrote. Why is this?

I can get the sub to work if I write it like,

```
 Public Sub Value()

 Dim X As Double

 Code in here...

 End Sub
```

However, I need to do it the first way. Is there something that I'm missing, that I need to include in my code to be able to write it the first way?

Comment: Looks fine to me. What error do you get? How are you trying to call that sub?

Comment: Are you providing an argument when you run it in your first example?

Comment: When I try to run it in VBA, I am prompted to enter a Macro name in the first example...so it's like it's not recognizing the sub I just wrote.

Comment: Isn't "X As Double" my argument? Or is that just my parameter?

Comment: @user6259845 Because you can't call it like that - you need to call it from another sub and give it an argument.

Comment: "Parameter" is `[ByRef] X As Double`. "Argument" is `42` in `Value 42` - note, procedures should be named strating with a verb. "Value" reads like a property, not like a procedure that *does something*.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See this example:

```
Public Sub Value(X As Double)

MsgBox X + 1

End Sub
Public Sub Test()

Value 2.2

End Sub
```

Running `Test` will give you:

[image: img1]